# How can I do disk partition in Ubuntu 18.04 while installing it?

Tags: disk, disk-utility

I don't need windows any more, I have 1TB of hard disk and 6gb ram.Please help me out I'm a beginner!

Comment: In Ubuntu installation procces, there is a disk-partitioning part. Just go through whole installation procces.

Comment: The boot loader process is the last one (Grub Install), if your Ubuntu seems working fine, the whole process is good, no worry about your Ubuntu install. If Grub was not properly installed, your computer was even not able to boot.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please do not change your question to a [completely different one](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1148732/2). Ask a new question instead.

Comment: Better duplicate if UEFI which all newer systems are: UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu But now swap not required as Ubuntu uses a swap file. Make sure it is gpt not very old MBR. Simple answer 500MB for ESP, FAT32, 25 ro 30GB for / (root) as ext4 and use rest as /home also ext4. Make sure drive is gpt for UEFI install.